# How to append file extensions .js to typescript?

Tags: typescript

In typescript I write the path without the extension -

```
import SomeClass from './some-class';
```

How to make after compilation, these paths contain an extension .js ?  Builds the project using gulp-typescript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> these paths contain an extension .js

You *don't need to*. Runtime systems (e.g. node, requirejs, systemjs) automatically assume a `.js` extension if you require a js file.